# Linq to Entities - Correlated Subquery

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
var query = db.DepoAccounts
   .Join(db.DepoAccountDetails,
         t1 => new { t1.INTEG_REF_NO, t1.BASE_DATE },
         t2 => new { t2.INTEG_REF_NO, t2.BASE_DATE },
         (t1, t2) => new DataCustomerAccountGDWHModel
         {
             BranchNumber = t1.BR_NO,
             BookedBalance = t2.DP_FACE_BAL_VAL_ADJ,
         }
   )).Where(ac => ac.BranchNumber == "500" &&
                (ac.AccountNumber.Substring(0, 1) == "H" || 
                 ac.AccountNumber.Substring(0, 1) == "F"));
```

How do I add to the above to do a correlated subquery?

```
AND DEP2.EFECT_DT = (SELECT MAX(DEP3.EFECT_DT) FROM 
R_DBLNK_US.DW_TRN_DEPO_ACC_DTL_D DEP3 
                WHERE DEP.INTEG_REF_NO = DEP3.INTEG_REF_NO
                      AND DEP.BASE_DATE = DEP3.BASE_DATE)
```

Comment: EF isn't a replacement for SQL, it's an ORM. It's *not* meant to gernerate correlated subqueries. Even JOINS are a strong smell - those should be generated by EF itself based on the entity relations. The `DepoAccount` *entity* (not table) should have an `AccountDetails` property, with the 1-to-many relation configured in the DbContext itself. There shouldn't be any need for such joins

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the comments. But I am in a time constraint here. Is it possible to do what I want as described?

Comment: That's exactly why you *shouldn't* try to do that in EF. ORMs aren't meant for reporting queries in general, not just EF or LINQ-to-EF. What you *can* do, is map entities to views - create an entity that matches the expected *result* and map it to a view that produces that result. You could also use [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) to call *functions* instead of views. You'll have to do that if your query requires passing parameters directly to a subquery for performance reasons.

Comment: You could also use *Dapper* instead of a full ORM to just execute the query and map the results. With reporting queries you won't use tracking so you don't really need a full-featured ORM.

Comment: Finally, you could use windowing and analytic queries to speed up even that `SELECT MAX()` subquery, eg with `FIRST_VALUE`,`LAST_VALUE` or even `MAX(DEP3.EFFECT_DT) OVER( PARTITION BY DEP.3.INTEG_REF_NO, DEP3.BASE_DATE.)`. A correlated subquery like this has to run once for every outer row. A ranking or analytic function with `OVER` though could be calculated in the same scan that produces the outer results, if the `ORDER BY` clauses match. None of those functions is exposed in LINQ-to-EF

Comment: Awesome response, my friend. Thanks. I'm going with Dapper.

Comment: Perhaps you could add __where__ you want to add the phrase, and provide conversion fro the SQL names (e.g. `DEP2`) to the Linq names?